# When putting string that into Excel spreadsheet it puts to Scientific notation or rounds up

Tags: excel, vb6

I am putting a string into excel. The string is often only numeric digits but can have alpha characters or hypens etc.

When I don't set the number format or set it like this
(Where xlSheet(0) is Excel.Worksheet)

```
xlSheet(0).Columns("N:N").EntireColumn.Columns.NumberFormat = "@"
```

It outputs in scientific notation.

When I use this code:

```
xlSheet(0).Columns("N:N").EntireColumn.Columns.NumberFormat = "0"
```

It rounds up the number to the nearest 100,000 so that the last five digits are 0's when they shouldn't be.

Should be: 1539648751235678942
But is: 1539648751235600000

The cells that have a hyphen or a letter aren't affected and work fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I add the data like this:

I loop through and put in `xlSheet(0).Cells(i, 14) = rs!value_number`

Where rs is my ADODB.Recordset

EDIT2: Herbert Sitz got it by adding an apostrophe before the text! Thanks everyone.

Comment: how do you put the string in?.

Comment: I loop through and put in xlSheet(0).Cells(i, 14) = rs!value_number

Where rs is my ADODB.Recordset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think problem is that the number you're trying to enter can't be accommodated exactly by Excel.  Excel has limitations on what numbers it display/represent because of the way numbers are stored internally.  In Excel's case numbers are limited to 15 digit precision (see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010073849.aspx ), which is not enough to represent your number.

You can enter the number as a string ("152..42") and all digits will be displayed, but you won't be able to perform exact mathematical operations with it.

Comment: Is there a way without changing how the data looks to force it to format as a string? I will never have to do mathematical operations.

Comment: Try
`xlSheet(0).Cells(i, 14).text = rs!value_number`

Comment: I don't use Excel much and don't have here to test, but I believe the way to force text formatting of numbers is to precede the number with an apostrophe character.  The apostrophe should become invisible once cell data is entered.  If you're setting value programmatically then prepend an apostrophe to the numeric string: "'" + mynumstring.

Answer (score 1):

For numbers, Excel can only handle 15 significant digits.

If you want to store a number that is more than 15 digits long without losing data, you have to store the data as text.

Doing what you've been doing will resolve the issue:

You can do either of the following to add your numbers as text:

```
xlSheet(0).Cells(i, 14).Numberformat = "@"
xlSheet(0).Cells(i, 14) = rs!value_number
```

Or

```
xlSheet(0).Cells(i, 14) = "'" & rs!value_number
```

Comment: Sorry someone already got it. This is the answer as well though. Thanks